# Configure Logstream Timestamp in NLog configuration fro Cloudwatch logs C# .Net Application

Tags: c#, .net, amazon-cloudwatch, nlog

I am trying to implement NLog for sending logs to AWS Cloudwatch.
The implementation works fine, the only issue I am facing is that whenever a log stream is created in cloudwatch its format is like:

Prefix - Timestamp - Suffix

I want to use today's date in place of timestamp and create a log stream, but the above format creates a log stream using the current date and time. Is there any way I can get something like:

Considering the current date as 20 September 2020, (2020/09/04)

Prefix - 2020/09/04 - Suffix

Comment: No it looks hardcoded: https://github.com/aws/aws-logging-dotnet/blob/f73951fc7cbed685dd5a27a8c6b8d5d04aaff521/src/AWS.Logger.Core/Core/AWSLoggerCore.cs#L501

Comment: Maybe create issue or even better pull-request with your idea: https://github.com/aws/aws-logging-dotnet/issues